# Piwik Filter Graph by Custom Variable

Tags: php, mysql, graph, analytics, matomo

In piwik, is it possible to filter the visitors graph based on a custom variable from the tracker? I want to show an evolution graph of all the visits with a `70` value in the first custom variable slot. I tried this call

> index.php?module=API&method=ImageGraph.get&idSite=1&apiModule=VisitsSummary&apiAction=get&token_auth=anonymous&graphType=evolution&period=day&date=2012-01-01,2012-07-10&width=500&height=250&filter_column=custom_var_v1&filter_pattern=70

but got

> No data for this graph.

When I remove the `filter_pattern` I get a graph. I checked the `piwik_log_visit` table in the database and I have that value for visit records.

Comment: http://piwik.org/docs/custom-variables/

Comment: I suggest to remove the "PHP" tag from this question. Now I can't (edit queue full).

Answer (score 0):

Create a segment with custom_var_v1 = 70 (I suggest setting it as pre-archived in case you have a lot of traffic).

Answer (score 0):

When you use **filtering:**

You are using filter_column and filter_pattern which are global Piwik API filters. But you must be sure the custom variable data is present in the report you're querying. The VisitsSummary.get method might not contain the custom variable data by default.

When querying data based on custom variables, use the **CustomVariables.getCustomVariables** API method rather than **VisitsSummary.get**.

Your query would look like:

*index.php?module=API&method=CustomVariables.getCustomVariables&idSite=1&period=day&date=2012-01-01,2012-07-10&token_auth=anonymous&filter_column=custom_var_v1&filter_pattern=70*

---

Try **Segmentation:**

Instead of filtering, try segmentation. The segment parameter allows you to segment the data by various metrics, including custom variables.
Try adding this segment parameter to your query:

&segment=custom_var_v1==70

Your query would look like:

*index.php?module=API&method=CustomVariables.getCustomVariables&idSite=1&period=day&date=2012-01-01,2012-07-10&token_auth=anonymous&segment=custom_var_v1==70*